# Fans of a new laptop relatively loud (when only browsing the Internet)

Tags: laptop, fan, noise

I bought a new laptop three days ago - Dell Inspirion 7577. I installed Windows 10 and drivers. I am only surfing the Internet for now and my fans are relatively loud which I find awkward for such a simple task for the hardware of that laptop. 
Is that normal?

Inside the house, the room the temperature is 27C° (if that is important information).

Specs of this laptop are:
-i7 7700HQ
-Geforce GTX 1050Ti
-1TB+SSD128GB
-8GB RAM

Comment: It is about 43°C for CPU and 38°C for GPU

Comment: now it rose to 53°C for CPU and 46°C for GPU

Answer (score 0):

Those temperatures are well within normal, and as dsstorefile notes, browsing the internet does not count as a "simple task" any longer.

Unless there is evidence of other issues, I would suggest this is entirely normal and not indicative of any particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a relatively powerful processor, which will generate a lot of heat.  Some makes/models of PC allow you to control the fan speed profile in the BIOS or even in a Windows application.  For instance, I have a homebuilt PC with multiple separately controlled fans.  I prefer to leave them at 50% most of the time, until the temp hits 60* C when the fans speed up to 75%.  At 70* C I have the fans speed up to 90%, which is loud and whining, and lets me know to close some applications or reduce the performance settings in my game.

Again, for me, it works best to have the fans working at a forgettable level, and not cycling up and down repeatedly.  It's also important to have the machine able to warn you "Too hot!" by spinning up the fans very loud.

If your make/model (Dell Inspirion 7577) doesn't allow fan control, then you have to do some detective work to figure out what's causing all of the heat generation.

Some of the sites you go to may be running Monero - use browser extensions like No Coin and AdBlock Plus.  If you're using Chrome, use the builtin Chrome Task Manager to see which sites are using the most resources.  Finally, if you're using many tabs, you might consider running fewer tabs.